# Change current link parameter in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony and Twig. I would like to change language to other clicking on links on header page. When I have current URL:

```
https://example.com/en/article-1/
```

I would like to list in :

```
https://example.com/en/article-1/
https://example.com/de/article-1/
https://example.com/fr/article-1/
```

En, de, fr are parameters from locale, saved in symfony.

Answer (score 1):

It's fully explained in the symfony documentation [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html).
Here is a sample

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/{_locale}/contact",
 *     name="contact",
 *     requirements={
 *         "_locale": "en|fr|de",
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function contact()
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this. I would like to show in template twig all available locales which I have.

Comment: A way to achieve this for example is by generating routes in the controllers in your available languages each time you render a twig template. With the returned values (routes), build in your case 3 html links with en, de, fr. These links must point to different language version of the current page